# It is not updating the row in table PDO

Tags: php

Can someone tell me why this code is not updating the the column in these rows please

```
$q2 = $db->prepare("insert into stat (clan_id,abbreviation) values (:cid,:abb) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE abbreviation=:abb");
            $q2->execute(array(
                ":cid"=>$somevalue,
                ":abb"=>$abbrev
                ));
```

abbreviation is my unique key in this table, there are more values but I removed some for clarity.

Edit:
Problem still exists, the PDO is adding new entries, however when it comes across a duplicate it is not updating

here is the table structure, there maybe something wrong here?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clan_id` varchar(168) NOT NULL,
  `abbreviation` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `abbreviation` (`abbreviation`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=155146 ;
```

Comment: Do you encounter an error?

Comment: There is no error ceejayoz

Comment: @ mario, is this the duplicate you refer to? values (:cid,:abb) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE abbreviation=:abb

Comment: `$q2 = $db->prepare("insert into stat (clan_id,abbreviation) values (:cid,:abb) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE abbreviation=:abb1");
            $q2->execute(array(
                ":cid"=>$somevalue,
                ":abb"=>$abbrev,":abb1"=>$abbrev
                ));`

Comment: I think mario is right: `:abb` is used in two different places in that prepared statement, which  PDO doesn't support. You'll need to change them to, say, `:abb1` and `:abb2`.

Comment: edited first post, new entry from Edit: